# Displaying ListView items in opposite directions android

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I have a ListView with a Custom adapter. Each row has a thumbnail, Title and descroiption.
I have a requirement where the List items i.e row content is displayed in the opposite directions of the screen. Meaning, the first row thumbnail and other content should be on left side, the second row content(thumbnail, title, description) on the right side and so on.

How can I achieve this?

This is my current code:-

list_row.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/> 


    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Title Of Song-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!-- Artist Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:textColor="#343434"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
       />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPubDate"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#97999C" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MyListAdapter.java

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
     static class LazyViewHolder
     {
         TextView title;
         TextView description;
         ImageView thumb_image;
         WebView imageWebView;
         TextView pubDate;

         String myTitle;
         String mydescription;
         String bitmapUrl;

     }
      public MyListAdapter(Context ctx, List<News> getList) 
      {
            mContext = ctx;
            data=getList;
            inflater =LayoutInflater.from(ctx);

            imageLoader=new ImageLoader(ctx);
        }
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View vi=convertView;
        LazyViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,null);

        viewHolder = new LazyViewHolder();

        viewHolder.title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        viewHolder.description = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.description); // artist name
       viewHolder.pubDate = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtPubDate);


                News song = data.get(position);

               myTitle =song.getTitle();


               //Set description
              mydescription =Html.fromHtml(song.getBody()).toString(); 


               // Set image
              bitmapUrl = song.getBigImage();

               //Set date
             myDate = song.getPublishedDate();





        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(myTitle);

        int i = 0;
        while ((i = sb.indexOf(" ", i + 40)) != -1) {
            sb.replace(i, i + 1, "\n");
        }
        viewHolder.title.setText(sb.toString());


        mydescription = mydescription.substring(0, Math.min(mydescription.length(), 50));
        viewHolder.description.setText(mydescription);



         viewHolder.thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image
         imageLoader.DisplayImage(bitmapUrl, viewHolder.thumb_image);






        return vi;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First way:**

Create two row layouts, one with the image on the left and one with it on the right. In your adapter, override `getViewTypeCount()` and return `2`. Override `getItemViewType(int position)` and return `0` for one type of row layout and `1` for the other (you can define constants if you want, but these are the values that need to be returned). Finally, in `getView()` you can call `getItemViewType()` for the position given and `switch` over the returned value. This determines which row layout to inflate, etc.

**Second way:**

Make one row layout with an image on both sides, both with `android:visibility="gone"`. Use the same layout for all rows, and make one of the two images visible using `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`. Choose which image to make visible however you like. (Make sure you call `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on the other image, in case this row is being recycled and the other image was made visible previously.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used the first approach. Works great now

Answer (score 0):

You can have two relative layouts in your row xml and in your getview, you can do like

```
if(position % 2 == 0)
{
    // This will be true for 0, 2, 4... rows
    // make firstRelativeView Gone
    // make secondRelativeView Visible
}
else
{
    //This will be true for 1,3,5,,.. rows
    // make firstRelativeView Visible
    // make secondRelativeView Gone
}
```

Both the relativeLayouts will have thumbnail, title and description but in the opposite direction. Set your image, title and description in this if else itself

Moreover, you can follow the below link. It is a tutorial on **How to inflate multiple views in a listview**

http://antew.com/?p=162

Answer (score 0):

You need to define 2 layouts, one for left and one for right with **same component ids**.

Than in your adapter (assuming you are using Cursor adapter)

```
    private int getItemViewType(Cursor cursor) {
        //some method that returns 1 for left layout, 0 for right layout
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2; //return 2 view types
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        //bind your view
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        int type = getItemViewType(cursor);
        int layout;
        switch (type) {
            case 1:
                layout = R.layout.row_left; //left layout
                break;
            case 0:
                layout = R.layout.row_right; //right layout
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown view type!");
        }
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        //initialize ViewHolder using same ids.
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

**list_row.xml**

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrLeft"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLeft"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLeftTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLeftDescription"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLeftPubDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#97999C"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrRight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtRightTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtRightDescription"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtRightPubDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#97999C"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgRight"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

**MyListAdapter.java**

public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        static class LazyViewHolder
        {
            LinearLayout lnrLeft;
            ImageView imgLeft;
            TextView txtLeftTitle;
            TextView txtLeftDescription;
            TextView txtLeftPubDate;
            LinearLayout lnrRight;
            ImageView imgRight;
            TextView txtRightTitle;
            TextView txtRightDescription;
            TextView txtRightPubDate;

        }

        private Context context;
        private List<News> newsList;
        private ImageLoader imageLoader;
        public MyListAdapter(Context context, List<News> newsList)
        {
            context = context;
            newsList=newsList;
            imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return newsList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return newsList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position)
        {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            LazyViewHolder viewHolder;
            if(convertView==null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null,false);

                viewHolder = new LazyViewHolder();

                viewHolder.lnrLeft = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lnrLeft);
                viewHolder.imgLeft = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgLeft);
                viewHolder.txtLeftTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLeftTitle);
                viewHolder.txtLeftDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLeftDescription);
                viewHolder.txtLeftPubDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLeftPubDate);

                viewHolder.lnrRight= (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lnrRight);
                viewHolder.imgRight = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgRight);
                viewHolder.txtRightTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtRightTitle);
                viewHolder.txtRightDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtRightDescription);
                viewHolder.txtRightPubDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtRightPubDate);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }else{
                viewHolder = (LazyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(data.get(position).getTitle());
            int i = 0;
            while ((i = sb.indexOf(" ", i + 40)) != -1) {
                sb.replace(i, i + 1, "\n");
            }

            if(position%2==0){
                viewHolder.lnrLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.lnrRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(data.get(position).getBigImage(), viewHolder.imgLeft);

                viewHolder.txtLeftTitle.setText(sb.toString());
                viewHolder.txtLeftDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(data.get(position).getBody()).toString());
                viewHolder.txtLeftPubDate.setText(data.get(position).getPublishedDate());
            }else{
                viewHolder.lnrRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.lnrLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(data.get(position).getBigImage(), viewHolder.imgRight);

                viewHolder.txtRightTitle.setText(sb.toString());
                viewHolder.txtRightDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(data.get(position).getBody()).toString());
                viewHolder.txtRightPubDate.setText(data.get(position).getPublishedDate());
            }

            return convertView;
        }
}
```